# Playing a Flash File in Android SDK

Tags: android, flash

I head Android 2.2 supports Flash, but I'm not sure what that means for the SDK user.

I'm using Android 2.2 platform (emulator and eclipse). In the emulator, I launched 'browser' app, and browser to the URL which has flash swf embedded, but I couldn't see it.

Am I missing something?

Comment: On my HTC Hero running 2.1 I can usually see an embedded YouTube video, but clicking on it opens it in another app. I'm not sure what you should see in a Froyo browser.

Answer (score 1):

You still need the separate Adobe Flash 10.1 software which is not part of the SDK.